# When/How should I use an authentication to check if the user can see a protected content?

Tags: video.js, mpeg-dash, drm

I am building a client side player(using videojs) which takes an mpd (protected) and play it. I would like to ask When/How I should make an authentication to check If the user that request a license from a license server(widevine,playready) is authorized to see the protected content.

```
player.ready(function() {
    this.src({
        src:'http://yt-dash-mse-test.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/media/car-20120827-manifest.mpd',
        type: 'application/dash+xml'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would authenticate the user even before showing the user the video playback page. But in addition to that, it is common to have some sort of authentication mechanism in your communication with the DRM License Server of choice. How to do this, depends on whether you are using a service provider that have this already defined, or whether you are planning to implement the license server yourself.

Comment: From what I've read. I think that using an authorized token to permit to get the manifest and an authentication token in the links where the mp4s are sitting is the way to go. I mean even if an unauthorized user managed to get the manifest and decrypt it with the license he still cant watch it because the authentication token it would expired or used.

Comment: @TonysAnsonīMisirgis In my experience, that same token is sent to the license server, and in many cases where you have DRM, it's not as common to use tokens for accessing the actual stream. It varies depending on region though.

Comment: I would like to ask if the license  server url is included inside the manifest or whether i need to define it inside the player .

Comment: With PlayReady it is normally defined in the manifest. Widevine doesn't provide that functionality and it is therefore player defined. FairPlay is like Widevine.